# Getting affected row count

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, .net-3.5

### **UPDATE 1:**

Does this look right?

```
Dim objSqlConnection As SqlConnection
Dim objSqlCommand As SqlCommand

Dim intAffectedRowCount As Integer

Function update_function() As Integer
    Using objSqlConnection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connectionString"))
        objSqlCommand = New SqlCommand("update table1 set col1 = @col1 where id = @id", objSqlConnection)

        objSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = strData
        objSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = intID

        objSqlCommand.Connection.Open()
        intAffectedRowCount = objSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objSqlCommand.Connection.Close()
    End Using

    return intAffectedRowCount
End Function
```

Does this close off everything opened properly?

---

### **ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I am currently using the following code to update a row in a database table:

```
objSQLConnection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connString"))

objSQLCommand = New SqlCommand("update table1 set col1 = @col1 where id = @id", objSQLConnection)

objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = strCol1Data
objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = intID

objSQLCommand.Connection.Open()
objSQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
objSQLCommand.Connection.Close()
```

If I run that query in sql server, it returns a message saying "1 row affected".

It's probably possible to access the same message from asp.net, but I don't know how to access it.

Even if I get a count, i.e. 1.

Anyone know how to get a count of the rows affected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs for [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Int32
>   The number of rows affected.

So where you're executing `ExecuteNonQuery` and currently ignoring the return value, just don't ignore it :)

(You should also use a `Using` statement to make sure that you don't leak connections etc.)

Comment: @nami: I would use a Using statement for the command as well, but yes, that's basically right. You could return directly from the `ExecuteNonQuery` call though - the `Using` statement will take care of closing the connection.